# Convection bake vs fan forced

Tags: baking, oven

I just got an oven with convection bake function, as well as a fan option. After reading up on convection baking to try and understand it I'm totally confused, I'm still not clear how convection baking is different from fan forced baking. Is there another heating element involved in convection baking besides the top and bottom elements? Does a different fan turn on when convection baking???? Please illuminate.